# Get token from request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I need to export token from `request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`. How can I export only the token from the string like this:

```
"Token token=\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHBpcmVkX2F0IjoiMjAxNy0wMy0yOCAwMDozMjozMSAtMDcwMCIsImlhdCI6MTQ5MDU5OTk1MSwiaWQiOjEsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJCb3NzIiwibGFzdF9uYW1lIjoiTWFuIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiYWRtaW4iXSwiZ3Vlc3QiOmZhbHNlfQ.eMoJjqY6FFWhAHxIihQ48JeHoo7z3wWMaApSWR6t4uo\""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into [ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.`token_and_options`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html#method-i-token_and_options):

```
token, _options = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.token_and_options(request)
```

But be aware of [the following Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28148) I fired some time ago. But for your case it doesn't matter until you need to work with `options` part.